# Нужна подсказка в общем вопросе по САПР

Tags: безопасность, сапр

Всем привет.
У меня есть задание найти информацию связанную с применением, какими-то изобретениями, интерестными тенеденциями развития, ученными и т.д. САПР в сфере информационной безопастности. Пол дня гуглил в интернете и так ничего толком не нашел. САПР в ИБ - практически ничего нету. Прошу вас ответить мне, если вы когда-нибудь сталкивались с подобным вопросом. Просто необходима подсказка в какой области искать (сама тема).
Возможно вы знаете то, чего не знаю я.

Comment: Какая вообще связь может быть между САПР и *информационной безопасностью* ? Разве, что картинки для презентаций оформить

Comment: Уточните задание дословно, тут или беда с задавателем, или вы что не так передали. P.S. ну и это не сервис для решения д.з.

Comment: да и я вот думаю, поймите меня правильно сам столкнулся с этим заданием и не знаю, что и предпринять

Comment: поэтому и не говорю делать его

Comment: просто хотел услышать коментарии специалистов. А вопрос стоит так: сделать доклад на тему применения САПР или их технологий в сфере ИБ.

Comment: Если кто **грамотно** смог применить САПР в сфере ИБ, это тема докторской на мой взгляд, а не доклада. Впрочем, ваша задача - лишь удовлетворить желания *"преподователя"*, у которого под вопросом либо компетентность, либо ЧСВ

Comment: простите,что означает последняя абревиатура?

Comment: последняя аббревиатура отлично расшифровывается поисковиком.

Comment: да, вы совершенно правы)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49142/discussion-between-4per-and-muscled-boy).

Comment: Хотя сама тема ИБ imho это что-то вроде псевдофилософии, попробуйте погуглить `case information security` (обычно термин CASE это у них САПР в software (CAD (computer aided design)  -- общий термин для САПР, CAM -- САПР машиностроения, CAE -- САПР электроники))

Comment: @avp, еше раз спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет не сталкивался. В теме информационной безопасности нет про сапр ничего. Может стоит посмотреть, истории взлома / защиты каких то САПР - программ.

Можно поискать следующую информацию в блогах, разработчиков САПР систем.

- Теория информационной безопасности
- Вычислительная техника и программирование
- Программно-аппаратные средства защиты информации
- Контроль безопасности в компьютерных сетях
- Техническая защита информации
- Криптографические методы защиты информации
- Безопасность электронного бизнеса
- Передовые технологии и продукты в обеспечении информационной безопасности
- Экономика защиты информации
- Системы защиты информации в ведущих зарубежных странах
- Управление информационной безопасностью предприятия

Comment: спасибо, возможно вы и правы